Embed SVG Figures as Data URIs in Quarto (not Inline SVGs) without CLI
I'm using Quarto to generate self-contained HTML reports and aim to embed figures as SVGs with data URIs rather than inline SVGs. I'm trying to avoid any CLI-based solutions.
This question builds on a previous RMarkdown issue, where I managed to embed SVGs as data URIs with the following configuration:
---
title: 'test'
knit: (function(input, ...) {pandoc::with_pandoc_version(version = '3.2.1', rmarkdown::render(input))})
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
---

```{r}
plot(1:10)
```

In Quarto, my current configuration still results in inline SVGs, not data URIs:
---
title: 'test'
format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    fig-format: svg
execute:
  fig-dev: 'svg'
---

```{r}
plot(1:10)
```

The issue likely stems from a version-specific Pandoc behavior.
In RMarkdown, I specified pandoc::with_pandoc_version(version = '3.2.1'), which achieved the desired data URI embedding. However, my attempts to activate a specific Pandoc version in Quarto have been unsuccessful, as the following setup fails to persist after a session restart:
> pandoc::pandoc_install('3.5', force = TRUE)
ℹ Installing Pandoc release 3.5
✔ Pandoc version 3.5 installed.
> pandoc::pandoc_activate('3.5', rmarkdown = TRUE)
✔ Version '3.5' is now the active one.
> Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = pandoc::pandoc_locate())

# After session restart
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] '3.2'

Is there a way to specify this Pandoc version directly in Quarto YAML or to set up a persistent Pandoc version across sessions?

contact the vendor: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions

Like in the linked question, this is still a version-specific behaviour of pandoc. Unless you want to downgrade to 3.1, you need at least pandoc 3.2.1 for this.

@margusl Many thanks for the cue. I updated my post.

Not exactly an answer, but after fiddling with this a bit I'd consider upgrading to quarto 1.6, it's bundled with pandoc 3.4.  It is pre-release and there still seems to be quite long list of issues marked with milestone:v1.6 - https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20state%3Aopen%20milestone%3Av1.6 - but 1.6 seems to be stable enough to present it as a default download option at https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/ . Or perhaps just replace pandoc executable in Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC") with the one in pandoc::pandoc_locate()

Thanks, @margusl! I upgraded to Quarto v1.6, but my Pandoc version remained at 2.1. To make the change permanent, I updated RSTUDIO_PANDOC in my .Rprofile to point to the desired Pandoc location, and that resolved the issue with SVGs embedded as data URIs.
Would you mind posting this as a formal answer so I can accept it? Thanks again for the guidance!
